# Recreating this SQL to LINQ (C#, NET 4.5)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql-server, linq

I have to query the database and to do so requires that I do quite a few inner joins and a couple of left outer joins. I've generated the SQL in a view but I am now having a bit of difficulty rewriting it to LINQ in my applications data layer.

```
FROM            dbo.Organisation 
INNER JOIN
                         dbo.EducationCourseVenue
 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.EducationCourseVenueLocation ON dbo.EducationCourseVenue.Id = dbo.EducationCourseVenueLocation.EducationCourseVenueId ON 
                         dbo.Organisation.GlobalEntityGUID = dbo.EducationCourseVenue.GlobalEntityGUID
 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.CommunicationType
 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.CommunicationTypeGlobalEntityMap ON dbo.CommunicationType.Id = dbo.CommunicationTypeGlobalEntityMap.CommunicationTypeId ON 
                         dbo.EducationCourseVenue.GlobalEntityGUID = dbo.CommunicationTypeGlobalEntityMap.GlobalEntityGUID 
INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Country 
INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Address ON dbo.Country.Id = dbo.Address.CountryId 
INNER JOIN
                         dbo.CountryRegion ON dbo.Country.RegionId = dbo.CountryRegion.Id ON 
                         dbo.CommunicationTypeGlobalEntityMap.CommunicationTypeItemId = dbo.Address.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.AddressPostalDistrictMap 
INNER JOIN
                         dbo.RegionItemDistrictMap ON dbo.AddressPostalDistrictMap.Id = dbo.RegionItemDistrictMap.Id
 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.RegionTypeItem ON dbo.RegionItemDistrictMap.RegionTypeItemId = dbo.RegionTypeItem.Id ON 
                         dbo.Address.Id = dbo.AddressPostalDistrictMap.AddressId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.RHSGarden
 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.AddressGeographics ON dbo.RHSGarden.Id = dbo.AddressGeographics.NearestRHSGardenId ON dbo.Address.Id = dbo.AddressGeographics.AddressId
WHERE        (dbo.CommunicationType.Code = 'AD')
```

This particular line of SQL is a problem for in LINQ

```
FROM            dbo.Organisation 
    INNER JOIN
                             dbo.EducationCourseVenue
     INNER JOIN
                             dbo.EducationCourseVenueLocation ON dbo.EducationCourseVenue.Id = dbo.EducationCourseVenueLocation.EducationCourseVenueId ON 
                             dbo.Organisation.GlobalEntityGUID = dbo.EducationCourseVenue.GlobalEntityGUID
```

I don't know how to do a join in LINQ without specifying key joins and then doing another join below that.

Any ideas?

Comment: look into a tool like `LinkPad` or show the Linq that you're using so that someone can perhaps pinpoint what you're doing incorrectly ...

Comment: As per @NLindbom's answer, looks like your original SQL is just a bit confused. SQL might allow that but the more readable equivalent is to have one ON clause per JOIN, which then makes it easier to translate to LINQ. Having said all that, views aren't evil and this might be a good candidate for keeping in a view instead of moving to LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

```
var q = from o in context.Organisation
        join v in context.EducationCourseVenue on o.GlobalEntityGUID equals v.GlobalEntityGUID
        join l in context.EducationCourseVenueLocation on v.Id equals l.EducationCouseVenueId
```

Is how i think of it, since your:

```
FROM            dbo.Organisation 
    INNER JOIN
                             dbo.EducationCourseVenue
     INNER JOIN
                             dbo.EducationCourseVenueLocation ON dbo.EducationCourseVenue.Id = dbo.EducationCourseVenueLocation.EducationCourseVenueId ON 
                             dbo.Organisation.GlobalEntityGUID = dbo.EducationCourseVenue.GlobalEntityGUID
```

Corresponds to:

```
FROM dbo.Organisation as o
    INNER JOIN dbo.EducationCourseVenue as v ON o.GlobalEntityGUID = v.GlobalEntityGUID
    INNER JOIN dbo.EducationCourseVenueLocation as l ON v.Id = l.EducationCourseVenueId
```